# Make Mercurial not to commit anything, unless the filenames are explicitly specified

Tags: mercurial, commit

according to Mercurial's commit help message:

> ```
> If a list of files is omitted, all changes reported by "hg status" will be
> committed.
> ```

Is there an easy way to change this behavior?

I'd like Mercurial not to commit any changes, unless the files are explicitly specified.

### edit

I am on Linux and I am using the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
$ hg commit -X *  
nothing changed
```

It doesn't do anything because all files are excluded, but if you give any files, those will be included.

You could alias it:

> [alias]
>   xcommit = commit -X *

then:

```
$ hg status
M a
M b
$ hg xcommit -m 'no files specified'
nothing changed
$ hg xcommit -m 'picking a' a
$ hg status
M b
```

Personally I wouldn't want to get used to this type of workflow. It's usually just as easy to:

- work in smaller chunks so your changes reflect a single changeset
- for the times when you forget and you're on a coding spree, use something like `hg record`
- for the really few times when the above two don't fit, use `-I/-X` for that single commit

Comment: thank you. This is what I was searching for. Thanx for the tips also.

Comment: Even if that wasn't the OP's motivation, +1 for the divination skills rather than just a command line :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using GUI like tortoiseHg you can select the files you need to commit. http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am on Linux and I am using the command line... I'll update my question.

Comment: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TortoiseHg it can do some on linux too. But I never tried.

Comment: @JayanthaLalSirisena your link is now at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TortoiseHg